# Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, struct, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass the ILTItem variable into my ILTViewController, triggered by AppDelegate.swift when the user launches my app via a deeplink.

The code I have errors with:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'

on the line where I define `ilt`.

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var ilt = ILT(homeworkID: 1234, title: "History ILT", subject: "History", teacher: "Miss A Smith", teacherCode: "asmith", studentID: 12345, description: "Description....", due: 1450137600, status: "In Progress", hasAttachments: true)
var newVC = ILTViewController()
newVC.ILTitem = ilt
appDelegate.window?.addSubview(newVC.view)
```

Why could this be? In my ILTViewController class I have:

```
class ILTViewController: UIViewController {
  // accept the incoming ILT struct
  var ILTitem: ILT!
```

IlT Struct Declaration:

```
struct ILT {
    let homeworkID: Int
    let title: String
    let subject: String
    let teacher: String
    let teacherCode: String
    let studentID: Int
    let description: String
    let due: Double
    let status: String
    let hasAttachments: Bool
}
```

Comment: Post your `ILT` class declaration

Comment: @redent84 I have added it

Comment: Your code works fine: http://swiftstub.com/580271845 . You've probably declared a `String` variable named `ILT` somewhere else and that's why it fails.

Comment: @redent84 That's not the issue, as when I combine it down to `newVC.ILTItem = ILT(homeworkID: 1234, title: "History ILT", subject: "History", teacher: "Miss A Smith", teacherCode: "asmith", studentID: 12345, description: "Description....", due: 1450137600, status: "In Progress", hasAttachments: true)` it still fails with the same message.

Comment: What I was saying is that you redeclared `ILT` (uppercase), not `ilt` (lowercase). The error is telling you that you are trying to call a `String` instead of a method (struct constructor in your case). And, as you can check in the link I provided, the error is elsewhere in your code, because the code you posted works fine.

Comment: @redent84 Oh, I see. Didn't realise variables and methods can clash names, I've found the problem now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Cool, I'll convert the comment to an answer so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are trying to call a `String` instead of a method (struct constructor in your case). You've probably declared a `String` variable named `ILT` (uppercase) somewhere else and that's why it fails.

Your posted code [works fine](http://swiftstub.com/580271845) so the error must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Related but slightly separate issue to the question - my `ILTViewController: UIViewController` class does not receive the new variable - `print`ing `ILTItem.title` returns null. Any idea why?

Comment: I recommend you to open a new question with the relevant code and preferably a self contained sample project reproducing the issue.

Comment: Happened to me when accidentally calling a KRProgressHUD.show()()   (double parenthesis accident)

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your let statement in if eg:

```
if let xxx = yyy {
   ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Works:

```
let works = ["foo", "bar"].first(where: { ($0 == "foo") } )
let works = ["foo", "bar"].first(where: { (_ in true) } )
```

Fails:

```
let fails = ["foo", "bar"].first(where: { (true) } )

// Cannot call value of a non-function type 'String?'
```

You must be sure to **use the parameter** (`$0` or `_ in`) in the closure expression.

Use `_ in` or `$0` to discard or reference the parameter. You cannot simple move directly into the closure body and return `true` or you will receive this (extremely unhelpful) error.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue in this code

```
array.first { $0 == item }
```

The problem was with `$0` not conforming to `Equatable` protocol. In my case it conformed to `NSObjectProtocol` and simple pointer comparison was enough, so I fixed the issue with

```
array.first { $0 === item }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had a problem with a similar error message.  I am writing a structure to handle Scalars for my library and needed a square root.
Error was

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Vsip.Scalar'

when calling sqrt.  Fixed it by explicitly calling sqrt as shown below. Hope this helps.

```
public var sqrt: Scalar {
        switch self.type {
        case .f:
            return Scalar(sqrtf(self.realf))
        case .d:
            let x = Foundation.sqrt(self.reald)
            return Scalar(x)
        case .cf:
            return Scalar(vsip_csqrt_f(self.vsip_cf))
        case .cd:
            return Scalar(vsip_csqrt_d(self.vsip_cd))
        default:
            precondition(false, "sqrt not supported for type \(self.type)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In messing around with Swift's various closure syntax types + autocomplete I often find myself in a mess of variables, return types, and using too few or too many sets of `()` or `{}`

I ended up with something like:

```
filenames.first(where: { $0 == filename } ) {

}
```

Which was giving the error

> Cannot call value of non-function type

Solution was to remove the trailing `{ }`, which is not correct in this form.

Should just be `filenames.first(where: { $0 == filename } )`

Check that you have not incorrectly applied a set of braces to the end of your non-function, etc., or some other hard to spot error in your current chosen Swift closure syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you haven't missed **?** for optionals.

That error can be shown for a different issue in a heavy-loaded schemes, like when I forget to mark optional.

`services.first(where: { $0.category?.id == categoryID })`