# Type 'Any' has no subscript members with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this topic has been discussed before, however I haven't found a solution on StackOverflow that worked in my code. What can I do to update my code so it runs on Swift 3? I did not have these errors in Swift 2.2

This is how I have my code formatted:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage


struct Comment {
    var image: String!
    var postID: String!
    var description: String!
    var username: String!
    var price: String!
    var rating: String!
    var title: String!
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?
    var key: String!


    init(postID: String, image: String, description: String, username: String, title: String, rating: String, price: String, key: String = ""){

        self.description = description
        self.postID = postID
        self.username = username
        self.title = title
        self.rating = rating
        self.price = price
        self.image = image
        self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    }

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

        self.description = snapshot.value!["description"] as! String // error here
        self.postID = snapshot.value!["postID"] as! String // error here
        self.title = snapshot.value!["title"] as! String // error here
        self.rating = snapshot.value!["rating"] as! String // error here
        self.price = snapshot.value!["price"] as! String // error here
        self.image = snapshot.value!["image"] as! String // error here
        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.ref = snapshot.ref




    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject] {

        return ["image": image, "description": description , "username": username, "postId": postID, "title": title, "rating": rating, "price": price]
    }


}
```

Comment: use `let keyValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>`, since `snapshot.value` is declared as `Any`.

Comment: @gabe You have to cast type Any to Swift dictionary type [String:AnyObject].Your snapshot is array of dictionary.

Comment: @Sachin-Vas Thanks. However, I then get the error 'Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' to type 'String!''

Comment: `let keyValue = snapshot.value as! [String: String]`, if you think all the values are string only then use the above.

Comment: @TusharSharma I still get the same error casting as [String:AnyObject]

Comment: @SachinVas Could you give me an example please

Comment: @gabe let keyValue = snapshot as! [String: AnyObject] and then loop within it to get values.

Comment: @TusharSharma Okay, so how can I run `let comment = description(postID: self.selectedPost.postID, description: textfield.text!, username: FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.displayName!)` without getting the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'"

Comment: @gabe is that previous issue resolved?

Comment: @gabe what is description a model class.?

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes. Here is a paste(http://pastebin.com/R01EGLdD) of my action, also note that it's in a TableViewController

Comment: @gabe Okk I will look into this but for now can you mark answer to your question correct if a make a post.

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes

Comment: Hi, the problem is that value can be any-type from `NSDictionary, NSArray, NSNumber to NSString`. Hence you need to identify the `type` of the object and then use the proper casting. Use `type(of: snapshot.value!)` and if's to identify proper Type.

Comment: @gabe have you declared description variable somewhere else in your code?LOOK WHAT THIS GUY EXPLAINS ABOUT THIS ERROR ITS PREETY CLEAR-:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039756/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-string

Answer (score 0):

**Try This-:**

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

       let keyValue = snapshot as!  [String:Any] 
       for data in keyValue
      {
       // Get your values
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work in your case:

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){
    guard let values = snapshot.value as! [String: Any] else {
        return
    }

    self.description = values["description"] as! String
    self.postID = values["postID"] as! String
    self.title = values["title"] as! String
    self.rating = values["rating"] as! String
    self.price = values["price"] as! String
    self.image = values["image"] as! String
    self.key = snapshot.key
    self.ref = snapshot.ref
}
```

let us know what you have got.

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'

Comment: change `snapshot.value as! [String: Any]` with `snapshot.value as? [String: Any]`. This will also need changing `values["..."]` to either `values?["..."]` or `values!["..."]`.